# Unity networking mouse position

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, 2d

I was following [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSetup.html) tutorial on the Unity docs, but wanted to change my version to fire towards the mouse position. The host works fine but when running the client the bullets fire towards the mouse position relative to the host client (usually just off to the side).

Here is my code as is:

```c#
public class PlayerMove : NetworkBehaviour {

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!isLocalPlayer)
            return;

        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 0.1f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 0.1f;

        transform.Translate(x, 0, z);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            CmdFire();
        }
    }

    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
    {
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdFire()
    {
        // create the bullet object from the bullet prefab

        // make the bullet move away in front of the player
        Vector2 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        Vector2 myPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1);
        Vector2 direction = target - myPos;
        GameObject projectile = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, myPos, transform.rotation);
        projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * 4f;

        // spawn the bullet on the clients
        NetworkServer.Spawn(projectile);

        // make bullet disappear after 2 seconds
        Destroy(projectile, 2.0f);
    }
}
```

I have also tried to move the "velocity = direction" to a new bullet script but it always performs the same.

How can I use a 'local' mouse position, if that's the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the direction, rotation and position from your client on all the other clients if you want them to see what client sees.

Also - `[Command]` only runs on the server, you probably want to spawn the bullet on all the clients connected to the server so you should run `[ClientRpc]` from your `[Command]`

```c#
public class PlayerMove : NetworkBehaviour {

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!isLocalPlayer)
            return;

        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 0.1f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 0.1f;

        transform.Translate(x, 0, z);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Fire();
        }
    }

    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
    {
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        Vector2 _target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        Vector2 _myPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1);
        Vector2 _direction = _target - _myPos;
        Vector3 _rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

        CmdFire(_myPos, _myDir, _rot);
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdFire(Vector2 _myPos, Vector2 _myDir, Vector3 _rot)
    {
        RpcFire(_myPos, _myDir, _rot);
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcFire(Vector2 _myPos, Vector2 _myDir, Vector3 _rot)
    {
         // create the bullet object from the bullet prefab

        // make the bullet move away in front of the player

        GameObject _projectile = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, _myPos, Quaternion.Euler(_rot);
        _projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * 4f;

        // spawn the bullet on the clients
        NetworkServer.Spawn(_projectile);

        // make bullet disappear after 2 seconds
        Destroy(_projectile, 2.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems to function better in the sense that each player (client and the host) can both control where they fire, but only on their own screen.

But they see the other player's bullets fire off towards the side (as before). I think it might be to do with an error I get when firing:

SpawnObject for BulletSprite(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject), NetworkServer is not active. Cannot spawn objects without an active server.
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkServer:Spawn(GameObject)
PlayerMove:RpcFire(Vector2, Vector2, Vector3) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMove.cs:64)